# MySQL, after migrating Latin1 to UTF8, LIKE searches no longer work. Tried all UTF8 collations

Tags: mysql, utf-8, internationalization, collation, data-migration

first question here. Been a long time lurker, really appreciate the immense help this site offers.

So, we completed the migration of a rather large system with hundreds of legacy components to UTF8. Thanks for all the fish, Latin1, but UTF8 is the future and this migration was obligatory.

So, everything works a dandy, except for LIKE searches on MySQL. I searched the other questions here but they all address the main issues of latin1 -> utf8 migration, but not searching, REGEX and LIKE....

For example, I try

SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE NAME LIKE '%SAO PAULO%'

and get zero results

SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE NAME LIKE '%SÃO PAULO%'

and get the expected results(note tilde on the A).

With latin1 the default collation latin1_swedish does the expected thing, considers A to be like Ã, and C to be like Ç. But with none of the UTF8 collations does this work.

What do I do? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you all and I hope to contribute to this community as much as it has contributed to my own work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard a guess and say you are using `utf8_bin`. You need to use `utf8_unicode_ci` to get proper comparisons like you are trying to do. It is slightly slower, but more correct.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the CONVERT function to convert your LATIN1 TO UTF8: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html

Also, maybe there was something wrong with the conversion, the following link looks like a good guide to convert a DB to UTF8 with some basic *NIX commands: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Convert_latin1_to_UTF-8_in_MySQL

Hope that made some sense. Good luck!